# algorithm arraylist remove String duplicates and save to new text file

Tags: java, algorithm, duplicates

I am currently writing an algorithm that creates an ArrayList from a .txt file, checks it with a loop for duplicates (where the loop should look like this:
Line one is written to new .txt & boolean found is set to true because the string was already found.
Line 2 is written to new .txt etc.
But if two strings are identical, the duplicate, i.e. the second string should just be ignored and continue with the next one).

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String suche = "88 BETRAG-MINUS VALUE 'M'.";
    String suche2 = "88 BETRAG-PLUS VALUE 'P'";
    boolean gefunden = false;
    File neueDatei = new File("C:\\Dev\\xx.txt");
    if (neueDatei.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("Datei wurde erstellt");
    }

    if (gefunden == false) {
        dateiEinlesen(null, gefunden);
        ArrayList<String> arr = null;
        inNeueDateischreiben(neueDatei, gefunden, arr, suche, suche2);

    }
}

public static void dateiEinlesen(File neueDatei, boolean gefunden) {

    BufferedReader reader;
    String zeile = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Dev\\Test.txt"));
        zeile = reader.readLine();

        ArrayList<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        while (zeile != null) {
            arr.add(zeile.split(" "));
            zeile = reader.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println(arr);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error2 :" + e);
    }

}

public static void inNeueDateischreiben(File neueDatei, boolean gefunden, ArrayList<String> arr, String suche2,
        String suche22) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(suche22);
    String lastValue = null;
    for (Iterator<String> i = arr.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String currentValue = i.next();
        if (lastValue != null && currentValue.equals(lastValue)) {
            i.remove();
            {
                writer.write(suche2.toString());
                gefunden = true;

            }

        }
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I know my code is wrong, but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: `dateiEinlesen()` should return the `ArrayList`, which you then pass to the `inNeueDateischreiben()` method. Currently, you don't return / pass the information. You currently only print the `arr` in your `dateiEinlesen()`.

Comment: You most likely get a `NullPointerException` right now, since you pass `null` to `inNeueDateiSchreiben()`. But the information about _what is happening_ is something that **you** should provide, instead of expecting people to figure it out.

Comment: How do you know it is wrong? Did you get an error message? Was there unexpected output? I've asked you four questions already now and you still haven't asked just one... :/

Comment: I get a NullPointException. Also The file is created, but nothing is written into it. Have now virtually started again from scratch, however, not even the file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable namings (suche2, suche22) makes reading the code difficult.

Other than that, your writing algorithm looks funny. You only compare adjacent lines while duplicate lines could be anywhere. In addition, `writer.write` only hits when you find a duplicate. Also how you call it and other things don't look right.

Here are some general steps to write this correctly:

1. Open the file so you can read it line by line.
2. Create a file writer
3. Create a set or dictionary like data structure that enables you to look up items in constant time.
4. For each line that you read do the following:

- Look if the line exists in the dictionary.
- If not, write it to the new file
- If it already exists in the dictionary, skip to step 4.
- Add that line to the dictionary for later comparisons and go to step 4.

5. When the lines are exhausted close both files.

I suggest, you rewrite your code completely as the current version is very difficult to amend.